# Excel IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH ignore certain characters

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, xlookup

Ultimately I'm trying to use a formula to see if a string in one cell has a partial match to what is in another cell while ignoring wildcards in between. . The formula I'm using in B2 to perform a partial search/match is

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Q2,J2)),"Matches","Review Req")

I'm wondering if it can ignore certain characters or use wildcards of some sort. Because as you can see it is not an exact match between

SE Ext. 22 and SE Ext '22 or SE Ext 22

OE 23 and OE '23 or OE23 or OE 23

SE 23 and SE '23 or SE23 or SE 23

[image]

and my limitation is formula ONLY is a very strong preference. Does anyone have a alternative to trying to do what I'm trying?

After getting help from below I got as far as this

So I tried to substitute and I got the result desired

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Q2,(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J2,"SE Ext '22","SE Ext. 22"),"SE Ext 22","SE Ext. 22"),"OE '23","OE 23"),"OE23","OE 23"),"_60K",""),"SE '23","SE 23"),"SE23","SE 23")))),"Matches","Review Req")

Comment: Did you read the documentation for ISNUMERIC and SEARCH? Do either of them mention wildcards?

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not really sure if its even applicable, as these are formulas I'm new to utilizing. But when I google it wildcards seems to pop up in what others have asked, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Which brings us back to my previous comment. **Did you read the documentation**?

Comment: Yes, but I am not understanding what I'm looking for still, when it still seems like others are possibly able to do so in their setup... thats why I'm asking here, again my apologies...

Comment: substitute() may help perhaps in a helper column.

Comment: It's better to post data as data, not picture. You can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Please also show what you expect in return. What do you expect for row 24 and 25 for instance. Also, it seems all values in Q are already aligned with the strings in J. What exactly are you after?

Comment: So I tried to substitute and I got the result desired

 

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J134,"SE Ext '22","SE Ext. 22"),"SE Ext 22","SE Ext. 22"),"OE '23","OE 23"),"OE23","OE 23"),"_60K",""),"SE '23","SE 23"),"SE23","SE 23")

 
now how do I combine with

 
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Q134,J134)),"Matches","Review Req")

 
all in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` to change "unwanted" characters in both strings and the do `SEARCH` (warning: this might cause false positives in some cases):

To `SUBSTITUTE` first column:

```
=REDUCE(A1:A4,{"'"," ","."},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"")))
```

To `SUBSTITUTE` second column (just change range):

```
=REDUCE(B1:B4,{"'"," ","."},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"")))
```

Combine it:

```
=IF(MAP(REDUCE(A1:A4,{"'"," ","."},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))),REDUCE(B1:B4,{"'"," ","."},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))),LAMBDA(z,x,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x,z)))),"Matches","Review")
```

Result:

[image]

If you want different characters to substitute, just add them to these arrays in formula *{"'"," ","."}*

Shortened version to `SUBSTITUTE` both columns at once:

```
=IF(LET(y,REDUCE(A1:B4,{"'"," ","."},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(y,,2),INDEX(y,,1)))),"Matches","Review")
```

If your original columns are separated by other columns, you can `HSTACK` them `HSTACK(A1:A4,B1:B4)` and use instead of range `A1:B4`

Comment: So I tried to substitute and I got the result desired

 

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J134,"SE Ext '22","SE Ext. 22"),"SE Ext 22","SE Ext. 22"),"OE '23","OE 23"),"OE23","OE 23"),"_60K",""),"SE '23","SE 23"),"SE23","SE 23")

 
now how do I combine with

 
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Q134,J134)),"Matches","Review Req")

 
all in one step?

Answer (score 1):

### Search Ignoring Specific Characters

- This uses a function that will create arrays of the strings to match per row:

  - If the string contains a dot, it will produce two strings (one with and one without).
  - If the last substring is 'numeric', it will produce two more strings for each string inserting a quote before the last substring.
  - If there are two strings so far i.e. there is no dot but the last substring is 'numeric', it will additionally produce a concatenated version of the strings.
- In the `MAP` 'rundown', the `SEARCH` function will try to find the lookup strings (in the array) in the source string resulting in an array of numbers and/or errors. The `COUNT` function will count the number of numbers and the `IF` function will produce the result accordingly.

```
=LET(sData,J2:J11,lData,Q2:Q11,ry,"Matches",rn,"Review Req",
    GetStrings,LAMBDA(str,LET(
        dot,IF(ISTEXT(TEXTAFTER(str,".")),
            HSTACK(str,SUBSTITUTE(str,".","")),str),
        quot,DROP(REDUCE("",dot,LAMBDA(rr,c,LET(
            s,TEXTSPLIT(c," "),t,TAKE(s,,-1),
            HSTACK(rr,IF(ISNUMBER(--t),HSTACK(c,
                TEXTJOIN(" ",,DROP(s,,-1))&" "&"'"&t),c))))),,1),
        IF(COLUMNS(quot)=2,
            HSTACK(quot,SUBSTITUTE(quot," ","")),quot))),
MAP(sData,lData,LAMBDA(s,l,
    IF(COUNT(SEARCH(GetStrings(l),s))=0,rn,ry))))
```

- Beware of false positives (examples in red; shouldn't be an issue with the original data).

[image]